# Seeking Water Quality Data for Lake Ontario that includes Dissolved Oxygen, Nitrogen, Phosphorus?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, canada

I was wondering what sources are available, or if anyone has GIS water quality data for the Great Lakes and specifically Lake Ontario?

We are interested in mapping Phosphorus, Organic Matter, Nitrogen and Dissolved Oxygen concentrations in Lake Ontario as they relate to algal blooms and hypoxia.

Answer (score 4):

The only data I could find on some of these parameters is from http://ontario.ca's 'Provincial (Stream) Water Quality Monitoring Network' which can be accessed at http://www.ontario.ca/environment-and-energy/provincial-stream-water-quality-monitoring-network .

The raw data is available from http://www.ontario.ca/environment-and-energy/provincial-stream-water-quality-monitoring-network-pwqmn-data in MS Access, Shapefile, and MS Excel formats where each row represents a sensor readings which include the following sensor descriptions:

- `PHOSPHORUS,UNFILTERED TOTAL`
- `NITROGEN,TOT,KJELDAHL/UNF.REA`
- `DISSOLVED OXYGEN`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I appreciate the help. This will do the job we need it to do. Appreciated

Comment: @JasonIgras Don't forget to click the green accept checkmark if this is the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some results for US data:
[National Water Quality Monitoring (US)](https://www.waterqualitydata.us/portal/)
[EPA EnviroAtlas](https://www.epa.gov/enviroatlas)
[Nitrogen and Phosphorus Pollution Data Downloads](https://gispub2.epa.gov/NPDAT/DataDownloads.html)
[National Lakes Assessment (US)](https://www.epa.gov/national-aquatic-resource-surveys/nla)
[National Aquatic Resource Surveys (US)](https://www.epa.gov/national-aquatic-resource-surveys)